# mySql Mistakes with the wrong symbol: is it a Tic, Comma, or Quotations?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the wrong syntax. It's confusing as a beginner to get mixed up with using the comma, quotation and the tic mark.

-list the form of government for the countries with the top 5 average GNP.

Here is the statement that I am using and the results.

```
SELECT 'avg-gnp','form-government' 
FROM country 
ORDER BY 'avg-gnp' 
DESC LIMIT 5;

+---------+-----------------+
| avg-gnp | form-government |
+---------+-----------------+
| avg-gnp | form-government |
| avg-gnp | form-government |
| avg-gnp | form-government |
| avg-gnp | form-government |
| avg-gnp | form-government |
+---------+-----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I've also tried this:  Thanks in advance!

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM country ORDER BY 'avg-GNP' DESC LIMIT 5;
+------+-------------+---------------+---------------------------+--------+-------------------+------------+--------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| code | fullname    | continent     | region                    | area   | year-independence | population | avg-lifespan | avg-GNP | form-government                              |
+------+-------------+---------------+---------------------------+--------+-------------------+------------+--------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| ABW  | Aruba       | North America | Caribbean                 |    193 |                 0 |     103000 |        78.40 |  828.00 | Nonmetropolitan Territory of The Netherlands |
| AFG  | Afghanistan | Asia          | Southern and Central Asia | 652090 |              1919 |   22720000 |        45.90 | 5976.00 | Islamic Emirate                              |
| AGO  | Angola      | Africa        | Central Africa            | 124670 |              1975 |   12878000 |        38.30 | 6648.00 | Republic                                     |
| AIA  | Anguilla    | North America | Caribbean                 |     96 |                 0 |       8000 |        76.10 |   63.20 | Dependent Territory of the UK                |
| ALB  | Albania     | Europe        | Southern Europe           |  28748 |              1912 |    3401200 |        71.60 | 3205.00 | Republic                                     |
+------+-------------+---------------+---------------------------+--------+-------------------+------------+--------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @ChrisKehl . . . Only use single quotes for date and string constants.  For escaping column names using backticks or double quotes in MySQL.

Comment: double quotes for escaping column names in MySQL @GordonLinoff that only works when you have enabled (ANSI_QUOTES) as sql mode otherwise it wil give a syntax error.. Without https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cp2zZerw28hywE3gvmg5w1/2 .. With https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cp2zZerw28hywE3gvmg5w1/1

Comment: Looks like I received the same thing.

Comment: mysql> SELECT "avg-gnp","form-government" FROM country ORDER BY "avg-gnp" DESC LIMIT 5;
+---------+-----------------+
| avg-gnp | form-government |
+---------+-----------------+
| avg-gnp | form-government |
| avg-gnp | form-government |
| avg-gnp | form-government |
| avg-gnp | form-government |
| avg-gnp | form-government |
+---------+-----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

Comment: @ChrisKehl use backticks around column/table name(s). backticks is `

Comment: I used the back ticks earlier, my result was  mysql> SELECT 'avg-gnp','form-government' FROM country ORDER BY 'avg-gnp' DESC LIMIT 5;
+---------+-----------------+
| avg-gnp | form-government |
+---------+-----------------+
| avg-gnp | form-government |
| avg-gnp | form-government |
| avg-gnp | form-government |
| avg-gnp | form-government |
| avg-gnp | form-government |
+---------+-----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

Comment: @ChrisKehl Please refrain from posting formatted content in a comment, as it becomes unreadable. Instead, edit your question to include your updates and properly-formatted query and output.

Comment: Use back ticks!

Comment: @TheImpaler hello, please follow the thread back ticks were used. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: SELECT ‘avg-GNP’, ‘form-government’ FROM country ORDER BY ‘avg-GNP’ DESC LIMIT 5;

Comment: Those are not back ticks. Those are single quotes. Back ticks are diagonal and go for up-left to down-right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a comment that cannot be put in a comment since comments don't allow back ticks. I wanted to make sure you got it right.

**Correct Form** (this is how it should look using **back ticks**):

```
SELECT `avg-gnp`,`form-government` 
FROM country 
ORDER BY `avg-gnp` 
DESC LIMIT 5;
```

**Wrong Form** (this is the way you had it using **single quotes**):

```
SELECT 'avg-gnp','form-government' 
FROM country 
ORDER BY 'avg-gnp' 
DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Do you see the difference?

And yes, MySQL is weird about this. The only database I know that uses back ticks (well... and MariaDB, of course).

Comment: How do I make those ticks on a macOS

Comment: @ChrisKehl it must be on your keyboard. Check to the left side of the number 1 on keyboard. You will see a tilda `~` and backtick

Comment: Thanks I see it.  So there is a difference in the ` which on a MAC is on the same key as the ~ .  Before I was using ' which is on the same key as ".

Comment: Just for the sake of argument, in order to avoid using back ticks, you can use underscores `_` instead of  dashes `-`. If you do, you don't need quotes or back ticks. For example the column could simply be named `form_government`. No back ticks needed.

Comment: Thank you  Madhur Bhaiya.  You solved my problem.  On a MAC keyboard the tic is on the far left side of the keyboard under the esc key [~ / `].  I was using the comma ' / ".  For a beginner this is hard to comprehend because they are close in comparison, and the mind wants to go the comma key because we use it so much in typing.

Comment: Backticks work in comments if you escape them `\\``, so you could write `SELECT \`col\` FROM`